# Genericise Function call

Tags: python

I am using a Python schedule library and setting up schedules for various days of the week.

```
schedule.every().monday.at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
schedule.every().tuesday.at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
```

I would like to replace the above two calls with one:

```
schedule.every().blah.at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
```

where `blah` can be monday,tuesday,wednesday,etc.

Comment: What library are you using? If it's designed well, it should have a nice way to do this, so you don't have to hack around it…

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the value of `blah` a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think any decent scheduling library would have a nice way to do this dynamically, maybe something like:

```
schedule.every('monday').at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
```

But if it doesn't, you can always dynamically access an attribute with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(schedule.every(), 'monday').at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
```

This is generally a bad idea… but if you have to work around someone else's library that doesn't make it easy to do it in a better way, that's a perfect example of why "generally" doesn't mean "always".

Either way, you can then, e.g., loop over the days you want:

```
for day in 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday':
    getattr(schedule.every(), day).at(x).do(doADayofWeekTask)
```

<sub>It is, of course, critical to chant 'monday tuesday wednesday thursday' in the voice of the Robotic Ghost of Christmas Past from the Future while typing this. Thousands of years ago, before the dawn of Python as we knew it, there was Guido.</sub>